# Ubuntu and Windows together

Tags: windows, ntfs, gparted

I have Ubuntu and Windows installed together. I want to reinstall Ubuntu but I need to add some space from Windows D: disk. Is there any chance in losing data and if not please give me instructions.

Ubuntu installer using gparted, yeah? Is there any difference between if I resize D: disk or while installing?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information. (I've done it for you in this case so you can see how it works)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reinstall ubuntu only to change the partition size, you don't need to do that. You can use GParted (System - Administration) to resize the partitions, reducing Windows D partition and increasing Ubuntu's partition without reinstalling.

To install gparted:

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

If you need to reinstall for another reason, you can also use gparted to resize the partitions before reinstalling ubuntu with the live CD. I think it is safer than to do it with the installation program as you can control better what you are doing.

EDIT after question edit:
I think you can get the same result with the installer and with gparted alone but I feel you have more options and control using gparted before than within the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installation disk should allow you to resize the Windows partition, but a backup is highly advisable.

Answer (score 0):

First off I should say that when working with partitioning there is always a chance something will go wrong. The advanced partitioning tool that ships in the ubuntu installer will allow you to change partition sizes as well as allow you to reformat and use your current Ubuntu and swap partitions for your reinstall.